# Getting out of a 2-branch mess in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a mess in git on 2 branches. `Frontend` contains a huge chunk of ongoing development work - it should have been fragmented into multiple branches, and it's a little messed up.

Here is the situation - `frontend` is on the left, top of `master` is on the right:

```
| frontend 1: newest commit (to be pushed)  
| frontend 2: recent commit (to be pushed)  
| frontend 3: week-old commit (this was a temporary save of lots of ongoing work - it probably should have been a stash. This one cannot be pushed)  
|  
|  | master: this is the current state of the site
|  | master: previous commit
| /
|/ 
| master before `git branch frontend`
```

On branch `frontend`, I'd like to:

- transfer `frontend 1` and `frontend 2` to `master` so they can be pushed now.
- 'cancel' `frontend 3` and move the code back to staging so I can make the commits properly (i.e. not in a huge dump of general work)

I am a beginner in git and I am worried I will do more damage (as I have already done) if I keep entering in commands trying to make it better. If you are able to help it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do an [interactive rebase](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) to rearrange the order of the frontent commits so `frontend 3` is the newest one.
2. Then, while on frontend, do a `git reset HEAD^` to "uncommit" frontend 3 while keeping the changes.
3. `git stash` to stash the changes from `frontend 3` as you meant to
4. Switch to master.
5. Merge `frontend` into `master`. (Or rebase, whichever it is you do.)
6. Pop the stashed changes wherever and continue working.

This assumes that the interactive rebase can in fact be performed cleanly – i.e. that the changes in `frontend 3` are unrelated to the ones in `frontend 1` and `frontend 2`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Could you comment on how this is different from the `cherry-pick`/`rebase -i` answers?

Comment: @sscirrus Once all is done the effect will be the same. My way you find out if the history of the `frontend` branch can be rearranged cleanly *before* you push instead of after, and avoiding replacing one mess with another. (Albeit one you'll have time to clean up after you get the good changes out.)

Comment: @sscirrus (I somewhat dislike cherry-picking, because it creates a copy of changes instead of just moving them around the tree, which sounds like asking for conflicts when later you want to merge the branches cleanly.)

Comment: Thanks - I've made it through half the steps (some issues with vim last night!) I stashed my working tree prior to step 1. If I stash `frontend 3` for step 3, is it possible to pop step 3's stash and then pop step 1's stash? +1 for your answer and comments so far, thank you!

Comment: @sscirrus I think that's how stashing works, really. The last thing you stashed will be the first thing you pop. So you stash whatever local changes you had before starting in step 1; stash `frontend 3` in step 3; then once all is done, pop `frontend 3` and clean that up; then after that, pop whatever local changes you had to begin with and continue work on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can `cherry-pick` the two commits you want back onto `master`.  Then `rebase -i` on `frontend` will let you reorder and break apart the commits on the branch however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to cherry-pick `frontend2` and `frontend1` into master, then also cherry-pick `frontend3` and do a soft reset.